# initWithContentsOfURL returns nil only in iOS 5.x

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I searched all topics about this issue but I couldn't find the answer.

I need to read a .txt file from a remote url and I use this

```
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@paco2.txt", downloadURL]] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

and download URL is

```
http://www.aaaaaa.com/
```

When I use the app in iOS6 or iOS7 works well, but in iOS5 the function returns nil.

The error is:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x1081e7f0 {NSURL=http://www.aaaaaa.com/paco2.txt}
```

I'm going mad looking for the answer.

Comment: I'm going mad looking what the error would print on the console...  ;)

Comment: sure hahahaha I was edit the topic ;)

Comment: check your internet connection it's may be down at a moments

Comment: The URL doesn't look good. How about `http://aaaaaa.com/paco2.txt` ?

Comment: The URL is another url, this is the format.